# Indoor rubber plant losing leaves

Tags: houseplants, leaves, watering, overwintering, ficus

This forum has been a great source of info and help for years, so before I begin, thanks to everyone who takes the time to pitch in with answers.

I've had a *ficus elastica* since December 2019. For the first year, it grew considerably, and is now about 5 feet tall from the floor to its highest leaf. Apart from repotting it once in that time, in spring 2020, I've never really had to worry about it, beyond learning how it likes to drink.

In the past month or two, however, it has been dropping its lowest leaves, which are yellowing first, a lot more frequently than ever before. In fact, I don't think it dropped any at all in the preceding winter. The house *has* been particularly chilly so far this winter, but I have reduced watering and I don't think the plant needs repotting just yet.

So my question is this: could the change in behaviour simply be the result of less daylight and fluctuating temperatures? Living in a flatshare, where not everyone is on the same page on heating, the place can go from very cold to toasty in a matter of hours. Alternatively, the plant is still producing new shoots and several leaves have appeared in the time that others have been falling off the bottom, so could it just be that the leaves are old and reaching a natural end?

I've included a few pictures [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AiSj8W3I8GA0iUIqr0ZAn65vjOnc).

Thanks for any and all advice.

George